# Actor Concurrency Model and Caching

Tags: caching, concurrency, message-passing

We use caching heavily within our software. The concept of a "put/get" datastore corresponds to the "Shared State Concurrency Model", which suffers from a number of disadvantages when compared to Message Passing concurrency (e.g. Actors).

How can we reconcile the Message Passing model with Caching? Or will we all be stuck with Shared State concurrency forever?

Answer (score 0):

Cache can be implemented as an actor, so that interaction with it (put/get operations) would take place through message passing. Depending on e.g. performance requirements, this solution may evolve into cache divided between more actors with some kind of ranges or another actor serving as a router.